# How to combine 2 lists into 1 dictionary using a function

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

These are the 2 lists I am trying to use:

```
names = ['joe', 'tom', 'barb', 'sue', 'sally']
scores = [10, 23, 13, 18, 12]
```

and I'm using a function I created named `makeDictionary` with the parameters `(list1, list2)`.

I do not want a direct answer in code, but how would I make the `names` list the keys in the dictionary, and the `scores` list the values in the dictionary?

Example output dictionary:

```
{'joe': 10, 'tom': 23, 'barb': 13, 'sue': 18, 'sally': 12}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what `zip` is for:

```
>>> dict(zip(names, scores))
{'joe': 10, 'tom': 23, 'barb': 13, 'sue': 18, 'sally': 12}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may simply do:

```
dict(zip(names,scores))
```

Output

```
{'joe': 10, 'tom': 23, 'barb': 13, 'sue': 18, 'sally': 12}
```